# How is the new price calculated in the pool based on reserves?

Tags: uniswapv3

Help me understand how the rate of the second token was known in advance?

Pool End

- Token A: `1200 + 3 + 0.3% = 1203.009`
- Token B: `400 - ??? = 399.003`

How to calculate the Token B `??? == 0.997` at the end?

https://docs.uniswap.org/contracts/v2/concepts/protocol-overview/how-uniswap-works

[image: uniswap]